# Unable to mock static methods with parameters using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, mockito, static-methods

I am trying to use some of the new features of Mockito, specifically mocking of static methods.

I am able to get it to work when the method I am mocking has no parameters, but for some reason it will not work if the method has any parameters.

As the example below is written, the test `assertEquals( "bar", Foo.foo() )` works but the test `assertEquals(2, map.size() )` fails as no behavior has been defined for the mocked class.

`fooMock.when(Foo::genMap).thenCallRealMethod()` gives the follwing compile time errors:

- The type Foo does not define genMap() that is applicable here
- The method when(MockedStatic.Verification) in the type MockedStatic is not applicable for the arguments (Foo::
  genMap)

`fooMock.when( (String s)->Foo.genMap(s) ).thenCallRealMethod()` gives these compile time errors:

- The method when(MockedStatic.Verification) in the type MockedStatic is not applicable for the arguments ((String
  s) -> {})
- Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method apply()

**Unit Test:**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void fooTest(){  
        try( MockedStatic<Foo> fooMock = Mockito.mockStatic(Foo.class) ){
            fooMock.when(Foo::foo).thenReturn("bar");
            assertEquals( "bar", Foo.foo() );
            //fooMock.when(Foo::genMap).thenCallRealMethod();
            //fooMock.when( (String s)->Foo.genMap(s) ).thenCallRealMethod();
            Map<String, String> map = Foo.genMap("1=one 2=two");
            assertEquals(2, map.size() );
        }
    }

}
```

**Class to be mocked**

```
public class Foo {

    public static String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }

    public static Map<String, String> genMap(String str){
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(String subStr : str.split(" ")) {
            String[] parts = subStr.split("=");
            map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

It looks like it is a simply a syntax issue, I am not super familiar with method references but I cannot figure out what the proper syntax would be.

Comment: This test does not make any sense. Also, you should test each method for that class separately.

Comment: This is just a simple example. I am actually trying to mock out a dependency to a utility class that I am testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the correct syntax

```
fooMock.when( () -> Foo.genMap(any()) ).thenCallRealMethod();
```

`anyString()` can be used, but there shouldn't be any difference because it's not ambiguous.

Comment: THANK YOU!  Once I created a anyString method it works.  Could you provide any links so I could better understand why this is the correct syntax?

Comment: @RichardFeynman you don't need to create the `anyString` method, that is an [argument matcher provided by mockito](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers). You can make a search for java8 method reference topic, which might get lengthily here.